# Install nodejs in jenkinsfile

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

I am trying to install nodejs on jenkins. The first step is to use a dockerfile with node as a base image. Recently, docker started to throttle pulls by anonymous users, so sometimes my image cannot be updated.
The fastest way I am trying to do this is by installing nodejs as a stage in my jenkinsfile. I followed the command as illustrated (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But the error is `sudo not found`.
May I know a better way to install nodejs in jenkins stage. I actually have a docker container in which I am running all my code and hence, it has all the essential packages. So, I do not think I can use plugin.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If that step in the pipeline is running as root, you don't need sudo. If you're running on regular (non-container) agents, you could install Node ahead of time rather than in the pipeline, which would save you a few seconds on each run. If neither of those work for you, you might find [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install) to be handy. Assuming curl, git, and make, this would work: `curl -sL https://git.io/n-install | bash -s -- -y` (see [here](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install#installing-n) for more options).

You could also have your pipeline log in, which would remove the throttling. Assuming you have Docker Hub credentials stored in Jenkins, that would look like:

```
// empty string meaning the default registry
docker.withRegistry('') {
  // do your work
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it worked as I can see `installed : v14.15.4 (with npm 6.14.10)` in logs but when I do `node -v` it complains `/home/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-pipeline@tmp/durable-55722c8a/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-pipeline@tmp/durable-55722c8a/script.sh: node: not found`
In my dockerfile, I have `WORKDIR /home/jenkins/` and I see while installing nodejs, it created folder within `/home/jenkins` so not sure why it is happening

Comment: Check the options in the link, you'll probably want to set N_PREFIX and/or add the install location to PATH.